# Why my code cannot stop? use fscanf

Tags: c

I want to continue read file until it ends,but it ouputs error answer and cannot stop.
my code is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void create() {
        FILE *fin = fopen("in", "r");
        int temp[4], t;
        int aaa;

        while ((aaa = scanf(fin, "%d:%d:%d:%d/%d", 
                      &temp[0], &temp[1], &temp[2], &temp[3], t)) != EOF) {
            printf("%d\n", aaa);
            printf("%d:%d:%d:%d\n", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);
        }

        fclose(fin);
    }

    int main() {
        create();

        return 0;
    }
```

and my input file content is:

```
103.29.43.0/24
103.29.5.0/24
103.29.52.0/22
103.29.56.0/22
103.29.60.0/22
103.2.96.0/22
103.29.64.0/24
103.29.65.0/24
103.29.66.0/24
103.29.67.0/24
103.29.7.0/24
```

but it outputs:

```
0
103:0:0:0
0
103:0:0:0
0
103:0:0:0
....(loop)
```

Comment: Compare `fscanf()` to 5 instead of `EOF`.

Comment: Please do not correct your code from the proposed fixes in comments and answers, it makes the inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- you pass `t` instead of its address `&t` for the last format specifier, invoking undefined behavior.
- The format string uses `:` instead of `.` as a separator, causing parsing failure.
- `fscanf` returns the number of fields it parsed successfully. Only upon end of file and if no field could be parsed does it return `EOF`. Otherwise, if there is a character in the input stream that does not match the format, it stops and returns between `0` and `5` for your format string. For example, a `.` in the input stream will cause your `while` loop to go on for ever with `fscanf` returning `0` as the `.` does not match `%d`.  **This explains the current behavior you observe**.

You should change the test to:

```
    while ((aaa = fscanf(fin, "%d.%d.%d.%d/%d",
                     &temp[0], &temp[1], &temp[2], &temp[3], &t)) == 5) {
        printf("%d\n", aaa);
        printf("%d:%d:%d:%d\n", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `fscanf` should have `.` instead of `:` between `%d` as that's causing mismatch.
2. Also use `&t` instead of `t`. See `man fscanf`
3. Also `while(fscanf() != EOF)` mean even if any matching failure occurs and `fscanf` fails to match and store all 5 arguments (which is happening here due to `:` and `.` mismatch) then too continue the loop.
   You should use `while(fscanf() == 5)` to continue the loop only when all the 5 arguments of `fscanf` gets matched and stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from a `FILE *` handle, you need to use `fscanf()` instead of `scanf()`.

For example, with `fin` as the `FILE *` here:

```
while (fscanf(fin, "%d:%d:%d:%d/%d",
              &temp[0], &temp[1], &temp[2], &temp[3], &t) != EOF) { ... }
```